# how can i validate console event after any action in cypress

Tags: javascript, console, cypress, console.log

Would appreciate help on this question.

i am validating javascript console log after certain action i perform, and validate that what is the status of the event when i forward the video.

#### Here is my code

```
it('testing', () => {
    cy.visit('https://youtube.com')
    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.get('.pp-ui-overlay.pp-ui-stretch.pp-ui-hidden > div > div').click({force:true})
    cy.get('.pp-ui-bar-range-thumb.pp-ui-bar-range-thumb-background')
    .invoke('attr', 'style', 'left: 70%;')
    .should('have.attr', 'style', 'left: 70%;').click({force:true})
    let spy
    Cypress.on('window:load', (win) => {
    spy = cy.spy(win.console, "log").  // can be other methods - log, warn, etc
    })
```

#### Here is the event

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggHbg.png)

#### what i want

i am visiting a site and i want to perform some action on a video which will trigger an javascript soncole event in console tab. after that action i want to validate that the what is the state of that event.

here i want to validae triggered event and check the state of the event

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the [`onBeforeLoad`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Arguments) option in your `cy.visit()` to spy on console log before all the logs occur. Here is a Gleb blog [example](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/listen-to-the-message/#spy-on-the-consolelog-method-call).

So for your case it would be:

```js
cy.visit('https://youtube.com', {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      cy.spy(win.console, 'log').as('log')
    },
  })
```